# NSTimer/Timer duration and UI update

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uikit, nstimer

Probably a simple question, however, I can't seem to conceive an elegant approach.

I want to design a trivial application that allows a timer to be set to a duration (say 1 minute), after that duration the timer should expire, *in* the duration the timer should update the UI every second.

Thus if the timer is set to one minute, the timer should fire, update the UI every second (by calling a method) and then finally invalidate after 1 minute.

My conundrum is, I can set a `scheduledTimerWithInterval`, it calls a method on the timer interval. If I make this 1 minute I can call a method after one minute to invalidate the timer, but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to perform calls during **this minute**.

Can you give me some guidance?

Comment: We can use two timers or we can use variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Swift 3.x code**

Make two global variables

```
var seconds = 1
var secondTimer:Timer?
```

Then make these two functions

```
// for setup of timer and variable
func setTimer() {
    seconds = 1

    secondTimer?.invalidate()
    secondTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

//method to update your UI
func updateUI() {
    //update your UI here

    //also update your seconds variable value by 1
    seconds += 1
    if seconds == 60 {
        secondTimer?.invalidate()
        secondTimer = nil
    }
    print(seconds)
}
```

finally call `setTimer()` wherever you want

Comment: Thank you. Is this really as elegant as it gets? It's seems very wasteful.

Comment: Other solution is to take two timers currently in my mind, but I guess that will be more wasteful than considering a single timer with a variable.

Comment: @Woodstock Do you have any improvements?

Comment: Your code sets `secondTimer` to `nil` and then tries to invalidate it. These two lines should be in opposite order. You code would also be nicer if you used a conditional unwrap rather than testing for `nil`

Comment: @Paulw11 Updated as suggested. Thanks

Comment: @Paulw11 May I know what's the need to have a variable `timer` as I have to make that `secondTimer` to nil forcefully which I cannot do on `timer` as it is already unwrapped from conditional binding. Thats why I just kept as `if let _ = secondTImer`

Comment: If you are going to unwrap the variable, you may as well use it and avoid the second conditional unwrap. If you are going to conditionally unwrap `secondTimer` anyway then you can just omit the `if` and say `secondTimer?.invalidate()`. In fact, now that I think about it, this is probably the best approach

Answer (score 3):

I would have done something like this:

1: Declare a `timer` and a counter:

```
var timer = Timer()
var counter = 0
```

2: Create a new function called for example `startEverySecond` that starts the timer with one second interval, this function is called after 60 seconds and will be called for 1 minute and then invalidate:

```
func startEverySecond() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(everySecond), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func everySecond(){
    if counter == 60{
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    counter = counter + 1
    print("Second")
}
```

3: Handle the start and stop of the timer:

```
// Start with 60 second interval
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(startEverySecond), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

// Stop
timer.invalidate()
```

So basically when you start your timer it will start off with 60 seconds and when this is done it will call the function `startEverySecond`and this will change the timer to call the `everySecond`function every second for 1 minute. To stop the timer just call `timer.invalidate()`